# Qlikview - no data to display

Tags: expression, qlikview, no-data

I have problem to show data in bar chart.

I want to show year in dimension and sum of price in expressions. Because I have a lot of data in bar chart I got no data to display.

I have idea to separate data by month like this

```
sum({<PostingMonth = {'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAJ', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AVG', 'SEP', 'OKT', 'NOV', 'DEC'}>} Price)
```

but also get no data.

If I show month by month I got result, how to sum all month to get value.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add PostingMonth as a second Dimension?